# Dialogflow CX return partial response

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have a Dialogflow CX V3 chatbot built with the Google Dialogflow console. I send it text chat using the REST API.

```
      const response = await sessionsClient.detectIntent(request);
```

And that works fine. But some routes in my Dialogflow agent have to call out to a webhook that may take time to respond. I want to use the `Return Partial Response` [feature](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#partial-response) to present a message to the user before the webhook is called. It doesn't make sense for that to use the REST API, because that only has the `sessionsClient.detectIntent` call, and that waits until the whole fulfillment is over before returning. It does have the [option](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/DetectIntentResponse) to return a `PARTIAL` result but that never seems to happen, and I cannot see how I might obtain any final result after a partial one.

I went to the RPC API which supports [long running operations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/how/long-running-operation), hoping to find a variant of `detectIntent` that returns an `operation` so I can query the [operation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#operations) multiple times. But I only [found](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#sessions)

```
rpc DetectIntent(DetectIntentRequest) returns (DetectIntentResponse)
```

and `DetectIntentResponse` [is not](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#detectintentresponse) an `operation`. Again, it includes a flag `responseType` which may take the value `PARTIAL`. However, if I see a partial response, I'm at a loss as to how to get any further output from my API call.

rpc `streamingDetectIntent` returns a response which can come in multiple pieces. But that seems only applicable to audio chat.

Can anyone please tell me how to use `Return Partial Response` with a text-based Dialogflow CX chatbot, please?

Comment: To add partial response in Dialogflow CX, you can follow this [link](https://dev.to/dhruv_rajkotia/partial-response-feature-in-dialogflow-cx-39bi#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20Simulator%20and,please%20take%20reference%20from%20screenshot.). For more information you can refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#partial-response). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: Sorry, neither of those links explain how to return multiple responses to a text-based chat link. I have a program linking google chat with dailogflow cx through the APIs to both services. How does that get multiple responses? What API calls? Thanks.